# Pass data from Application to the Activity

Tags: android, events, android-activity

My android Application class instance is listening to the third-party service for the event. Then the event is coming out, I need to notice my Activity about it. What is the right way to do that?
I know about startActivity() method, but my Activity is running yet!

Comment: Are you talking about broadcasts? If so check this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Local broadcast events with LocalBroadcastManager - see this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for more information.

I have copied relevant bits of code from the above tutorial for your convenience.

To notify your already running activity about your event, try the following:

1. Send a broadcast intent from your Application class when you receive the event.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
   // add data
   intent.putExtra("message", "data");
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
2. Register a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity which will handle the received Intents for your event. Add the following code to your Activity:

   ```
   @Override 
   public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
     new IntentFilter("my-event"));
   }

   // handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
   private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // Extract data included in the Intent
       String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
       Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
     }
   };

   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
     // Unregister since the activity is not visible
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
     super.onPause();
   }
   ```

Comment: That's what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the communication is local to your app you can use [local broadcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/5433102).

For communication between components you can also use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/README.md) (Android-library). It is really easy to use and implement (takes less than a minute to understand how it works) and is great in performance.